# Calculate hypothetical stock value in n years at todays' dollars?

Tags: stocks, inflation, compound-interest

I'm new to investing.

If I buy hypothetical stock that meets this criterion:

- 100 shares at $100 per share
- Shares increase in value by 10% per year
- Inflation is 2% per year

In today's dollars, what will the value of the stocks be in  25 years?

**Edit:**

- Dividend is 5%
- Tax rate is 30%

Answer (score 1):

Real growth is 8% per year, so in n years one share will be worth (in today’s money): 100 x (1.08 ^ n). Remember not to ignore dividends when calculating the total return.

Comment: Is there, by chance, a typo in that formula?

Comment: @MikeScott If we take 30 years as an example, 100*(1.10^30)/(1.02^30)=963.33; 100*(1.08^30)=1006.26.

Answer (score 1):

The question cannot be fully answered due to missing details:

- What is the taxation?
- How much dividend does the stock pay?

...but, the correct formula for zero taxation and zero dividend is 100*100*(1.10 / 1.02)^25.

So the value will be 66040.88 dollars, IF there is no tax, and IF the stock does not pay any dividend and will not pay any dividend in the future.

Comment: Thank you. As per your comment, I've added dividend and tax information to the question. Cheers.